# Expiring a value based on a date field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `course offerings`. In this table you will find each course with its respective `course_start_date` and `course_end_date`.  I am also using an enum field called `course_status`. There are two possible status for each course `IN SESSION` or `Closed` but not both. How could I create a query that will change the status to `Closed` if it is passed its `course_end_date`? [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/812d1)

```
CREATE TABLE course_offerings 
    (
     id int auto_increment primary key, 
     course_name varchar(20), 
     course_start_date date,
     course_end_date date,
     course_status enum('CLOSED','IN SESSION')
    );

INSERT INTO course_offerings
(course_name, course_start_date, course_end_date, course_status)
VALUES
('Math', '2013-02-20', '2014-02-20', 'IN SESSION'),
('Science', '2013-02-20', '2014-04-18', 'IN SESSION');
```

Comment: UPDATE course_offerings SET course_status = 'Closed' WHERE course_end_date > SYSDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is a dynamic way to do what you are trying.

This simple SQL query can help you update such records:

```
UPDATE course_offerings 
SET course_status = 'Closed' 
WHERE course_end_date < SYSDATE
```

Comment: Where is `SYSDATE` date coming from? the mysql server right?

Comment: its system's current date

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
UPDATE course_offerings 
SET course_status = 'Closed' 
WHERE course_end_date = "passed_date";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
update course_offerings set course_status='Closed' where course_end_date<str_to_date('2014-02-02','%Y-%m-%d');
```